# System hangs on changing time

Tags: time

My machine is always showing an hour ahead of the actual time. I am in Texas currently but the time never picks Day light savings. Any time I click on Set Time(Top Right Corner), my system just hangs right there. I have to turn off the machine each time. how do I fix this issue?
[image]

This is what happens when I try ntpdate: still 1 hour difference.

```
ntpdate time.nist.gov 
13 Dec 21:44:37 ntpdate[3098]: bind() fails: Permission denied 
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov 
[sudo] password for ubuntu: ntpdate[3237]: step time server 192.43.244.18 offset - 12.151112 sec
```

Comment: When you reboot, does your system changes the time, or does it stay as before you changed it?

Comment: No, time stays the same.

Comment: What exactly do you click on when the system freezes? Just the time and date in the top panel?

Comment: @Stefano, I have added the snapshot of the button I am clicking.

Comment: Is your Hardware clock set to local time or UTC?

Comment: @lazypower, Hardware clock was showing a time diff too.. time is in sync now after changing it hardware clock but I can still not change time from Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: Okay but the time is correct now after rebooting? I'll do a little more digging into why you're ubuntu-desktop time settings arent being propigated. Can you give me a detailed list of your hardware setup off the books utilizing lspci, dmesg, hwinfo, uname -ar, cat /etc/issue and send that to my personal email at coder.chuck at gmail dot com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a console alternative to setting it from the gnome-panel time applet?
ntpdate is a favorite of mine. i have it setup in a cron script across several Machines and VM's to ensure my system clock never gets skewed that far off. (once a week is fine by my standards. i find that I only migrate away from Atomic Time a few microseconds a week.)

However, with that said, give a try with

```
 ntpdate time.nist.gov
```

and see if it corrects your time issue, without a freeze.

If your system continues to freeze, see if you cant ssh in from another machine and have a look at /var/log/messages. On a Fedora system at one point i was 2 hours ahead of actual time, when i reset the date, it caused a panic because everything on the system was 2 hours ahead. Threw some ridiculous error about future time and locked up. I powered down the machine for a day and gave it another go in a recovery console without an issue.

**Edit 1:** Another thought occured to me to try and change your TimeZone settings. See if that will reconfigure your clock. See the article located at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime

This may be a byproduct of messed up TZ settings.

Comment: Tried your solution, Still 1 hour difference. ubuntu@ubuntu-XPS-M1330:~$ ntpdate time.nist.gov
13 Dec 21:44:37 ntpdate[3098]: bind() fails: Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu-XPS-M1330:~$ sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
13 Dec 21:45:14 ntpdate[3237]: step time server 192.43.244.18 offset -12.151112 sec
ubuntu@ubuntu-XPS-M1330:~$

Comment: @t3ch Remember to update your original question with each thing you try, I've gone ahead and added it for you.